# Infinity-groupoid on the etale site of a scheme.

Tags: infinity-categories, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.  We may naturally associate to $X$ a simplicial set which is a Kan complex.  This in turn gives rise to the fundamental $\infty$-groupoid associated to $X$.  From this object we can recover the usual fundamental groupoid associated to $X$.  In this way we can view the fundamental groupoid as a higher dimensional decategorification of an $\infty$-groupoid.

Now assume that $X$ is a scheme.  There is a natural concept of the the etale fundamental groupoid associated to $X$.  More precisely the objects are geometric points of $X$ and morphisms are isomorphisms of the associated etale fibre functors.

My question is the following:  Is there a concept of the etale fundamental $\infty$-groupoid associated to $X$, from which we can recover the usual etale fundamental groupoid as in the topological setting?

Comment: Yes: it is due to Artin and Mazur.

Comment: @Moosbrugger: care to add a reference?

Comment: Artin and Mazur, "Etale homotopy type", Lecture Notes in Mathematics 100. See also Friedlander, "Étale homotopy of simplicial schemes", Annals of Mathematics Studies 104.